# Typescript interface problem: how to get the type like t when we have a const like list

Tags: typescript, typeof, keyof

```
const list = [
  {
    label: "phone",
    defaultValue: "1203981209",
  },
  {
    label: "isMan",
    defaultValue: false,
  },
  {
    label: "age",
    defaultValue: 22,
  },
];

type t = {
  phone: string;
  isMan: boolean;
  age: number;
};
```

We have list.And how to get t in Typescript.
I tried to write something like `type t = {[k in typeof list[number]["label"]]: typeof list[number]["defaultValue"];};`,but that does not work.

Comment: Why not create an interface for members of list?

Comment: I want to create a type for the props that passed into child component. 
The prop mabe like the list.

Comment: I don't 5hunk I understand what your saying. You can create types for lists too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original object needs to be typed well for this to work - since you want the literal `label` values for the keys in the new object, they need to be `as const` so they don't get widened to `string`. (I don't see a nice way to use `as const` over the whole object, because then the *values* don't get widened - if you went that route, you'd have to have a helper type to turn, eg, `"1203981209"` into `string` and so on).

```
const l = [
  {
    label: "phone" as const,
    defaultValue: "1203981209",
  },
  {
    label: "isMan" as const,
    defaultValue: false,
  },
  {
    label: "age" as const,
    defaultValue: 22,
  },
];
type T = {
    [Prop in typeof l[number] as Prop["label"]]: Prop["defaultValue"];
};
```

Comment: How would such a helper work?

Comment: I don't know if there's an easier method, but something along the lines of `T extends number ? number : T extends string ? string :` etc

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended going the other way, if your use case allows, with something like

```js
interface PropertyDefaultValue<K extends keyof t = keyof t> {
  label: K;
  defaultValue: t[K];
}

const list: PropertyDefaultValue[] = ....
```

That said, while I was writing this, @CertainPerformace posted their answer and I think I like theirs better than mine in many use cases.

That said, mine doesn't require that all default properties be defined.

Also, are you sure this is the way you want to go? I've always defined an object with my default values, then fleshed out my objects using `myFilledObj = Object.assign({}, myDefaultObj, mySpecificObjBeforeFillingDefaultValues)`