# How to add type to make below code not prompt type errors in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

```
const obj = {
  extend: (p: {
    property: string;
    methods: { name: string; call: string; params: number }[];
  }) => {
    obj[p.property] = {};
    p.methods.forEach((m) => {
      obj[p.property][m.name] = (params: any[]) =>
        m.call + "____" + params.length;
    });
  },
};

obj.extend({
  property: "Scope1",
  methods: [
    {
      name: "functionName",
      call: "function_name",
      params: 1,
    },
  ],
});
// How to add type to make below code not prompt type errors in typescript. In typescript, this code below will prompt type errors.
console.log(obj["Scope1"].functionName(["firstParam"]));
```

How to add type to make that code not prompt type errors in typescript.
obj extend methods, all the methods were putted in one property.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very generic Requirement regarding how the `extend()` work.

To avoid the type errors and make it generic we can define an `ObjectTemplate` to satisfy the Typescript compiler so that we can assign a value to the object on the fly.

```
type Args = {
    property: string;
    methods: { name: string; call: string; params: number }[];
}

type ObjTemplate = {
  extend: (args: Args) => void;
  [k: string]: any
}

const obj: ObjTemplate = {
  extend: (p: Args) => {
    obj[p.property] = {};
    p.methods.forEach((m) => {
      obj[p.property][m.name] = (params: any[]) =>
        m.call + "____" + params.length;
    });
  }
};

obj.extend({
  property: "Scope1",
  methods: [
    {
      name: "functionName",
      call: "function_name",
      params: 1,
    },
  ],
});

console.log(obj["Scope1"].functionName(["firstParam"]));
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM5QLxQN4FgBQV9RhwD2kcoAXFEsHAJYB2CA3LgVALYTAAWxAJkioYoDAIZcqNek2ZQAxmIA2SqbUYtCYuBKGiArhwBGEOFAC%20AbQC6rHOdy5QkKAHkjAKwAqEDmCViwNDo2HhQEAAeQQz8VAAU2shU8MgAlGgAfFAAbsR0-Hb4lgDWajII1lRiDCC4Dji48sQMNFDEnlTu3r7%20gcGYbOFREDHxYMmISOmoWaHs7R6WYAB0RKSmoNZomOaFBCtcvAJIywBmxHAAomLyPHFxHNOzg-OeS6skZJuWHMviXFt0HEwNpdFUajYni92JxlooVFAANRQABEAH0MWiUUitDoOCclCMELw9vhzKk9vVdo4cAtlpFovw4nNCJ8NiAqCiAMpNSAARhRABpBoc%20IIqJZoSz2P8IJzTvoGPJgHRmgA5CQQIXQ-Dw1SohVKlXNNGy7VhdggvF6PnCi0WO34ax28l2RrNJDEQnLJTEBBxBaWbm8iAC6xnRXK1UMDVcOJB050OA0AAKoI4KOsqQpQA)

Answer (score 0):

According to [typescript-interface-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71432913/typescript-interface-problem-how-to-get-the-type-like-t-when-we-have-a-const-li) I find one answer.

```
export const obj = {
  extend: <T extends string, O extends string>(a: {
    property: T;
    methods: { name: O; call: string; params: number }[];
  }): {
    [Prop in typeof a as Prop["property"]]: {
      [Prop in typeof a.methods[number] as Prop["name"]]: (
        ...args: any
      ) => Promise<any>;
    };
  } => {
    const obj = {} as any;
    a.methods.forEach((method) => {
      obj[method.name] = (...args: any) => {
        return Promise.resolve("success");
      };
    });

    const newObject = {
      [a.property]: obj,
    };

    return newObject;
  },
};

const extendedObj = obj.extend({
  property: "Scope1",
  methods: [
    {
      name: "functionName",
      call: "function_name",
      params: 1,
    },
  ],
});
```

After that, we can get this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please explain what exactly you did to solve their problem? Or summarize what you learned from the link you referenced? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is a good reference for what to include in an answer. Thanks for participating in the community!